# Bootstrap modal will not show up

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to implement the login and signup forms of my site as a bootstrap modal, but the modal is not showing up at all after clicking the link inside the navbar. I have encountered on couple of similar questions on this topic before, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. JQuery is included so I have no clue what could be causing modal to be shy to show up. Can anyone help, please? Code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="Mc8MyxbLVQ93MY1dMlbE6y9NXzlTiVrVB80P0lYl">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mypage.me/css/app.css">

        <title>MyPage</title>
         <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <style>
          body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
          }

          .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("/images/ukay3.jpg");

            /* Full height */
            height: 100%;

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
          }

          .navbar { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Logi</a>

    <!-- Old Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Section: Logo and collapse button -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a style="display:block; margin:7px; margin-right:20px" href="/ " class="pull-left"><img 
    src="/images/logosmall.png" alt="Not found!"></a>
    </div><!-- End Section: Logo and collapse button -->
      <!-- Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Market</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About<span class="caret"> 
     </span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/about">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    <!-- Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://mypage.me/register"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                        </ul><!-- Right Side of Navbar --><!-- End Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    </div><!-- End Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="container">

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to MyPage.com</h1>
    </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use `button` instead of `a` and try to put modal at the end of `body` content

Comment: Have you imported also Bootstrap's CSS in your real project?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="Mc8MyxbLVQ93MY1dMlbE6y9NXzlTiVrVB80P0lYl">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mypage.me/css/app.css">

        <title>MyPage</title>
         <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <style>
          body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
          }

          .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("/images/ukay3.jpg");

            /* Full height */
            height: 100%;

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
          }

          .navbar { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Logi</a>

    <!-- Old Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Section: Logo and collapse button -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a style="display:block; margin:7px; margin-right:20px" href="/ " class="pull-left"><img 
    src="/images/logosmall.png" alt="Not found!"></a>
    </div><!-- End Section: Logo and collapse button -->
      <!-- Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Market</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About<span class="caret"> 
     </span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/about">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    <!-- Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://mypage.me/register"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                        </ul><!-- Right Side of Navbar --><!-- End Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    </div><!-- End Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="container">

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to MyPage.com</h1>
    </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your cdn is not supporting your code  i have added cdn of bootstrap4 below

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="Mc8MyxbLVQ93MY1dMlbE6y9NXzlTiVrVB80P0lYl">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mypage.me/css/app.css">

        <title>MyPage</title>
         <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <style>
          body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
          }

          .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("/images/ukay3.jpg");

            /* Full height */
            height: 100%;

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
          }

          .navbar { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Logi</a>

    <!-- Old Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Section: Logo and collapse button -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a style="display:block; margin:7px; margin-right:20px" href="/ " class="pull-left"><img 
    src="/images/logosmall.png" alt="Not found!"></a>
    </div><!-- End Section: Logo and collapse button -->
      <!-- Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Market</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About<span class="caret"> 
     </span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/about">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Page3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    <!-- Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://mypage.me/register"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                        </ul><!-- Right Side of Navbar --><!-- End Section: Right side of Navbar -->
    </div><!-- End Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="container">

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to MyPage.com</h1>
    </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the bootstrap css into the `head` of your `html`: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>MyPage</title>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         
         <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        </head>
    <body>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="container">

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to MyPage.com</h1>
    </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to import bootstarp css files to the head before the app.css.
something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Mc8MyxbLVQ93MY1dMlbE6y9NXzlTiVrVB80P0lYl">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mypage.me/css/app.css">

    <title>MyPage</title>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("/images/ukay3.jpg");

            /* Full height */
            height: 100%;

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Logi</a>

    <!-- Old Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Section: Logo and collapse button -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a style="display:block; margin:7px; margin-right:20px" href="/ " class="pull-left"><img
                        src="/images/logosmall.png" alt="Not found!"></a>
            </div><!-- End Section: Logo and collapse button -->
            <!-- Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/posts">Market</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About<span class="caret">
                            </span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/about">Page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">Page2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">Page3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Section: Right side of Navbar -->
                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="http://mypage.me/register"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul><!-- Right Side of Navbar -->
                <!-- End Section: Right side of Navbar -->
            </div><!-- End Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Welcome to MyPage.com</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link bootstrap.min.css file in you current code and define proper classes on modal html section. Check below code it is working fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Mc8MyxbLVQ93MY1dMlbE6y9NXzlTiVrVB80P0lYl" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mypage.me/css/app.css">

    <title>MyPage</title>
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <style>
      body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .bg {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("/images/ukay3.jpg");

        /* Full height */
        height: 100%;

        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      .navbar { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
      </style>
    </head>
<body>

<!-- Old Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Section: Logo and collapse button -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  <a style="display:block; margin:7px; margin-right:20px" href="/ " class="pull-left"><img 
src="/images/logosmall.png" alt="Not found!"></a>
</div><!-- End Section: Logo and collapse button -->
  <!-- Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/posts">Market</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About<span class="caret"> 
 </span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/about">Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">Page3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
<!-- Section: Right side of Navbar -->
<!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://mypage.me/register"><span class="glyphicon 
 glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
            </li>
                    </ul><!-- Right Side of Navbar --><!-- End Section: Right side of Navbar -->
</div><!-- End Section: Collapsible part of Navbar -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Login Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal End -->      <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to Mohd. Aslam</h1>
</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. This worked, modal fade class was causing problems.

Comment: Welcome Andrezinho